# Can i remove panel-body background in bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm tried to remove or change panel-body background to transparent. but not work... 
 please help me

i want to change white colour to the transparent, please see the image attached.

This is my code in bootstrap.css

```
.panel-body {
background: transparent;
}
```

This is my code in login page

```
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background-image: url("login.jpg");
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-top: 50px">     
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="panel panel-default">   
        <div class="panel-body">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'welcome/login' 
?>">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" 
class="form-control" >
                    <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" 
placeholder="password" class="form-control" >
                    <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                        
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn- 
primary">
                </div>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>          
    </div>
   </div>   
  </body>
```

[my login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q48Ch.png)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dwvZ.png)

Comment: what is your bootstrap version ?

Comment: my bootstrap version : 3

Comment: you can see this URL as Reference: 
1. https://codepen.io/jybjones/pen/LGPrWZ
2. https://codepen.io/DLady/pen/rxRLGj

Comment: paste your code. i'm not clicking on links

Comment: I'm newbie in bootstrap, may u explain about that link?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `.panel` background:

```
.panel{
    background:transparent !important;
}
```

Or

```
.panel{
    background:unset;
}
```

Comment: @EkoPrasetyoWibowo please share your html code too.

Comment: this code in my bootstrap.css

   .panel-body {
background: transparent!important;
}

.form-group {
background: transparent!important;
}

.form-control {
background: transparent!important;
}

and this code in my login page

<div class="panel panel-default"> 
   <div class="panel-body">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'welcome/login' ?>">
     <div class="form-group" >
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control" >

Comment: @EkoPrasetyoWibowo In the answer I told you that you must remove `.panel` class background, just append `.panel{background:transparent}` to bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answers...

this is my final code

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="background-color: transparent; border: 2px 
solid red;
border-radius: 4px;">
```